# Min Max like function, using if best == None with the condition inside the loop in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, nonetype

In function where we need to search for the best element according to a condition (like Min Max functions: search the min or the max), I saw some (or many) peoples check if the variable that hold the best answer is None inside the loop side by side of the condition checking.

To illustrate the point, let the following 2 source code:
A) use the test `is None` inside the loop:

```
list_vals = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

min_val = None

for val in list_vals:
    if min_val is None or val<min_val:
        min_val = val

print("min = ", min_val)
```

B) The best recive the first element

```
list_vals = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

min_val = list_val[0]

for val in list_vals:
    if val<min_val:
        min_val = val

print("min = ", min_val)
```

My Questions are:

- Why some peoples are doing the first form (A) ? is it some good practice ?
- If we use the first from, that's mean on each iteration we check if the variable is None, I don't know if the compiler optimize this or not.

To see for this example if the execution time is similaire or not, I computed the time for both method *A* and *B* with

```
nb = 100000000 # 100_000_000
list_vals = random.sample(range(nb), nb)
```

- time(A) = 24.00 s
- time(B) = 19.31 s

I repeated the test with other length, and the result is the same, the B method is alyse (relatively) faster than the A method.

Thank you for your help.

Edit one:  let assume that list_vals is not empty. Thank you [@0x5453](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3282436/0x5453)

Comment: One important difference is the behavior when `list_vals` is empty.

Comment: @0x5453 yes indeed , very good comment. we assume that list_vals is not empty, or we can check it once. And after that the question remain , check the variable is none at each iteration.

Comment: @0x5453 yes, but why don't check that before the `for` is just one simple `if not len(list_val)` vs. checking in all iterations `if min_val is None`. I know that using the keyword `ìs` to compare with `None` is faster than doing `min_val == None`, but you are doing it in all iterations.

Comment: @PaulM. but then you return inf if the list is empty, which is not a very intuitive behaviour

Comment: @PaulM. yes , the same idea. The goal is to initialize the best value depending on the situation, after doing the loop.

Comment: you can also loop on `list_vals[1:]` (skipping the first element, since you've already seen it)

Comment: @njzk2 that creates a slice of the list instead of just a view. For big lists, it might be more expensive to slice the list and copy the slice to new memory than to simply retest the first element

Comment: @njzk2 yes, can do it from 1 to len(list_vals)-1 , my problem is "for not empty list", why some people include the test if best_value is None Or.... inside the loop. so the method A, rather than the method B.

Comment: @ibra An elegant solution would not need to add constraints like that, and work on any length

Comment: _"Why do some people do A rather than B?"_ Who knows? Maybe they want more easy-to-understand code (not that any python programmer worth their salt will be confused by B). Maybe they don't know that B is faster? That is not an answerable question.

Comment: As for _"I don't know if the compiler optimize this or not."_: evidently not, if A consistently takes longer than B according to your experiment.

Comment: @njzk2 what do you mean by elegant solution and constraints, we always work with constraints, and this also related to the data we have and the size ...etc.

Comment: @ibra if your function works _only_ for input of size > 0, you need to have a test at the begining of your function to validate that constraint, and you need to throw an error if that constraint is not met. On the other hand, if your function also work in more generic terms, like for 0-length lists, then you don't need such test and such exception.

Comment: @njzk2 yes of course you're right. My problem is for the repeated non necessary  check (if variable is None) in the first form, imagine we have a very big length.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi good point. One could use `itertools.islice`, or a `range` on the indices to avoid the duplication, but it's not much of an improvement in terms of readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general code, you may want to work with arbitrary iterables, not just `list`, in which case only the first form works at all (you can't index non-sequences). You may also need to handle potentially empty inputs (A handles them by producing `None`, while B raises an `IndexError`). It does add non-zero cost (CPython has only the simplest, most local of optimizers; it can't make broad deductions like "`min_val` is only `None` on the first loop"). If performance is critical, you can get the best of both worlds (though with slightly uglier code) this way:

```
vals = ... could be any iterable ...

iter_vals = iter(vals)  # Explicitly convert to iterator (if already an iterator, just returns vals at trivial cost)

min_val = next(iter_vals, None)  # Pulls first value, or None if vals was empty

for val in iter_vals:  # Iterates rest of values looking for minimum
    if val < min_val:
        min_val = val

print("min = ", min_val)
```

In this scenario, you don't make assumptions about the input being a sequence, you make no unnecessary copies of data (which slicing `list_vals[1:]` would do), you don't have to invent a sentinel value for the initial case, because you can safely acquire the first element once, and you don't test the initial value against itself (because stateful iterators only produce the initial value once).

Comment: So, it goes for the form B, with some care for general cases.

Comment: @ibra: Sure? The only way to not perform the test that is guaranteed true in n - 1 of n cases is to not perform it, so the resulting code would inevitably look more like form B. You're avoiding n - 1 unnecessary tests by doing a *tiny* bit more work setting things up.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, so I am still not understanding why some peoples do the form A. maybe they just don't realize that fact of testing n-1 times a condition which is true, or maybe for clarity (readability )  or maybe for  not doing extra steps before the loop. It is still bizarre for me, because whatever the reason, it is not more important than wasting n-1 check.

Comment: @ibra: Because 99% of the time, the performance doesn't matter, and simpler-to-read/maintain beats faster. That's the trade-off in using Python in general; it's more expressive, faster to write, typically more readable, but you pay for it in speed (and before anyone brings up Cython or PyPy or numba or the like, those involve other trade-offs that sometimes gain you speed, but change the rules for optimization, or restrict certain constructs, etc., etc., so it's really just another set of trade-offs, not a free speed up). Most of the time, wasting `n - 1` cheap tests for `None` doesn't matter.

Comment: @ibra: And as noted, form A has advantages (not raising exceptions for empty inputs, which is a mixed bag admittedly, not requiring a sequence, etc.). My answer (form C for short) is strictly better (on speed, support for arbitrary iterables, no memory overhead, etc.) than A or B *except* that the explicit conversion with `iter` and `next` makes the setup less intuitive for people not used to those built-ins, given they're rarely used (plus, for very short inputs, it's likely a titch slower due to slightly higher setup costs, though that's meaningless given the benefits on longer inputs).

Comment: And of course, we've both "wasted" far more time discussing this than we'd save if we ran a program containing the "inefficient solution" a million times for inputs of size one million, so the most efficient solution is, as usual, the one that is simple, correct, and doesn't involve endless hand-wringing over which is the best solution. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much :) ,  SO the Real Answer is here down in the comment hahah , Thank you again :)